# 100% open ports false positive on scanning external Ip's

Tags: security, nmap, port-scanning

Got a new vps server, which is having a strange problem.
I tried a number of port scanning utilities (nmap, masscan, zmap, etc), any port I scan on any external Ip is detected as open.
Tried disabling the  firewall, replacing Ubuntu with Debian, nothing helps. Can't see any possible related errors in journalctl records.
What could possibly be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to a network device inline, e.g. an F5 load balancer using SYN cookie protection. You can verify that with `nmap --reason`, `-vv`, or `--packet-trace` to determine what TCP flags you get back.